# HTML table come border lines every 3 column

Tags: html, css, border, tr

I want to wrap each 3 tr as a red outline.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RbiUb.png)

"test", "image", and "click" is tr element each of them.
I want to wrap this with red outline.

Any ways to visualize this with css?

Comment: Some pseudos might get you there, but it's gonna be ugly. A nested table would probably be better.

Comment: Is this tabular data (then definitely use a table), or are you using a table for layout (in which case consider CSS grid or flex box layout instead)?

Comment: well i intended to implement card layout, 3 rows, 3 columns.

Comment: Please show enough HTML and CSS in your question so that we can see the structure. Otherwise we are just guessing at what might be a good solution.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can give the first tr border top the last tr border bottom and middle tr border left and right it will enclose it in a border which will look like all of them are in a box.
You can do that by giving them ids and then selecting them.